# JIB file positioning with performance impact?

Tags: maven, jib

We build our Java application using jib-maven 3.2.1 in a Jenkins pipeline. In the configuration we have:

```xml
<configuration>
  <extraDirectories>
      <paths>
         <path>
            <from>target/libs</from>
            <into>/opt/hcl/keep/libs</into>
         </path>
      </paths>
  </extraDirectories>
</configuration>
```

to provide libraries for the classpath. Worked like a charm. Recently we notices a drop in one of our performance metrics from 400ms to 1700ms. Our tester investigated and found something puzzling. When executing the following commands inside a build image and restart, the metric went back to 400ms:

```bash
cd /opt/hcl/keep/
mv libs libs-new
mkdir libs
cp libs-new/* libs/
```

we are puzzled what might cause that? What could we investigate?

Comment: I have no clue at all, but does `lib/` have symbolic links?

Comment: Nope, no symbolic links. We started to investigate using https://github.com/wagoodman/dive

Answer (score 0):

We found a partial answer thanks to [Dive](https://github.com/wagoodman/dive). The drop happened when we upgraded dependencies to a newer but `-SNAPSHOT` version. Apparently gib places snapshot jars in their own layer.

Moving to a non-snapshot version fixed the performance degradation.

What is still missing (I'll update when I learn more): why the performance difference due to existence in different layer.